# Volume on MacBook Pro low after disconnecting from Bluetooth speakers

Tags: audio, bluetooth, sound-volume, speakers

As the title suggests, I am having issue with the volume of the internal speakers from my MBP after I disconnect from the Bluetooth speaker. This doesn't happen always, but it seems to happen with both my headphones and with the speaker, so it is not one device specific.

Currently, my volume is at maximum levels, but it is very quiet, probably around 50% of maximum value. I have tried killing all `coreaudiod` processes, trying to unload and load `/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext`, checked all the levels everywhere, tried turning off Bluetooth, but nothing seems to help.

Any suggestions what might be causing this? I am running the latest MacOS version, 10.12.6.

Comment: i have same exact problem on 2017 MBP; except i can't make the volume get back to normal at all. Restart doesn't help.

Comment: I'm wondering if there has been a fix to this. I'm on High Sierra version 10.13.6 (17G65). I have the same problem when I disconnect my bluetooth speakers, my Macbook's volume remains permanently low. Unless I fully shut it down.

Comment: @ppanana I really didn't notice this problem recently, as I wrote in my answer that High Sierra seems to have fixed it. Now, I do use bluetooth less, so maybe I just didn't happen to notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has not appeared so far in latest version of macOS, High Sierra, so I guess this can be fixed by upgrading to the latest software.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved resetting the NVRAM

Comment: You mean you solve the issue temporarily by resetting the NVRAM, or the issue doesn't appear anymore?

Resetting NVRAM requires reset of machine, so I can solve the issue with simple reset as well, but the sound issue comes back once a week or so when tinkering a lot with Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 1):

NO it didn't, I just updated mine to OS Catalina and still the issue exists. I'm hoping somebody can fix this issue.

Comment: Can you edit this to expand this into a complete answer? This seems more like a reply or comment or “me too, I have this issue” based on the brevity of the answer.

Comment: This problem came back recently. I can reproduce it 100%.